# How to extract date from a column that has URLs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column named 'path' which has some URLs and I need to extract the date that is coming after the word News

Example -

1. ex1-/News/2010/May/03/Ribbon-cut-on-new-HQ/
2. ex2-/India-Team-Cricket/News/2012/July/26/This-cricket/

There can be many dates in the URL. But the requirement is to extract the 1st occurrence of date which is coming after '/News/'

Output - a new column that has dates as below

1. 2010/May/03
2. 2012/July/26

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (mysql, postgres, sql server, oracle, snowflake etc)

Comment: Hi .I am using SQL server

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the tags to reflect that and hopefully pull in an expert to solve this for sql-server to provide an answer/direction on this one.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: what version of sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is for SQL Server 2008 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @tbl Table  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Tokens) VALUES
('ex1-/News/2010/May/03/Ribbon-cut-on-new-HQ/'),
('ex2-/India-Team-Cricket/News/2012/July/26/This-cricket/');
-- DDL and data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '/';

SELECT ID, tokens, pos -- position of the News token/element
    , c.value('(/root/r[sql:column("pos") + 1]/text())[1]','CHAR(4)') + @separator + 
        c.value('(/root/r[sql:column("pos") + 2]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') + @separator + 
        c.value('(/root/r[sql:column("pos") + 3]/text())[1]','CHAR(2)') AS Result
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
         REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
         ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.query('for $r in /root/r[./text()="News"]
    let $pos := count(root/r[. << $r]) + 1
    return $pos').value('text()[1]','INT')) AS t2(pos);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| ID |                         tokens                          |    Result    |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | ex1-/News/2010/May/03/Ribbon-cut-on-new-HQ/             | 2010/May/03  |
|  2 | ex2-/India-Team-Cricket/News/2012/July/26/This-cricket/ | 2012/July/26 |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Given that that oldest version of SQL Server that is supported is 2012 and SQL Server 2008 hasn't been supported since 2019, you probably don't need to specify the version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/kpViwY/1

The regex I used: News/(\d{4}/.+/\d{2})

Comment: Can you please tell me the full SQL query ?

Comment: OP is using sql server where regex, for whatever reason, is still not supported.